# Toggling fieldset component in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some nested json data that i want to hold inside a fieldset and the default display option is to show them hidden. I have this example http://jsfiddle.net/jnvq9twr/

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    My Account
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
 <form>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Line Height</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="nam" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Top</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="nme" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="ne" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>

    </div>
        <fieldset class="row border p-2">
   <legend  class="w-auto">Business Data</legend>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="ne" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="ne" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
        <select class="form-control"><option>USA</option><option>Canada</option></select>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I am thinking of having a hide or show inside the fieldset line just to the extreme right. Is it possible to have a button inside a second legend to the right or is the fieldset made to take only one legend?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it this way http://jsfiddle.net/v3foLhsn/1/

The css

```
    .card-header{
        background-color:#324148 !important;
        color:white !important;
    }
    .form-control{
        width:80% !important;
    }
    #toggle + #content {
    display: none;
}
#content{
    width:100% !important;
}
#toggle:checked + #content {
    display:block;
}
    legend {
    width: 85%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

legend label {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: inherit;
}

legend label::after {
    content: "▼";
    float: right;
}
.gml{
    margin-left:2% !important;
}
.w-auto{
    width:50% !important;
}
```

The html

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    My Account
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
 <form>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Line Height</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="nam" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Top</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="nme" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="ne" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>

    </div>
        <fieldset class="row border p-2">
   <legend  class="w-auto"><label for="toggle">Business Data</label> </legend>
     <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked="" hidden=""/>
     
      <div id="content">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="ne" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="ne" placeholder="Ime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
        <select class="form-control"><option>USA</option><option>Canada</option></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Bottom</label>
        <select class="form-control"><option>USA</option><option>Canada</option></select>
    </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form> 
  </div>
</div>
        </div>
```